# squid proxy: character failure on chinese web sites

Tags: character-encoding, proxy

I set up a squid 2.7 on my windows 7 64bit Notebook in transparent mode. Other Notebooks can access the internet over the proxy on my notebook, but over the proxy the webpages are not displaying the chinese character signs the way they should.

I found something like `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to write into the first line, but it didn't help.
The error with the broken characters occours from the first hit.
The Webpages are encoded in UTF-8 and delivered from the proxy in UTF-8.

EDIT: I found out that the encoding Problem only occurs if I open a Webpage on an other Notebook that is connected over my PC. If I use the Proxy locally on my PC the character encoding is fine. Russian Website dont have the Problem either, its only chinese and japanese.

Any solutions to this problem?
THX  a lot.
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out that the damned Notebook which showed the broken characters didnt have the eastern language support installed. Arrggg. Everything is fine with the proxy. Spend hours of my life for such a crappy mistake.